# A visual explanation regarding a generalised Pearson's correlation for two variables

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, pearson-r

This is a textbook exercise that might be seen as a generalisation of Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient between two variables, with multiple groups each having variable sizes:

> Let there be $k$ groups of data of size $n_j$ on two variables $(x,y)$, with means $(\bar x_j,\bar y_j)$, variances $(s_{xj}^2,s_{yj}^2)$, and correlation coefficient $r_j$; $j=1,2,\ldots,k$. Then the correlation coefficient of the combined data of size $\sum_{j=1}^kn_j$ is given by
>
> $$r=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^kn_jr_js_{xj}s_{yj}+\sum_{j=1}^k n_j(x_j-\bar x)(y_j-\bar y)}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^kn_js_{xj}^2+\sum_{j=1}^kn_j(\bar x_j-\bar x)}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^kn_js_{yj}^2+\sum_{j=1}^kn_j(\bar y_j-\bar y)}}\quad,$$
>
> where $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ are the grand means of $x$ and $y$ respectively.

The exercise also asks to explain from the above formula that $r_j$ may be zero for each $j$ and yet $r$ may be non-zero

While I am not that interested in an analytical derivation of the above expression, I would like to have an intuitive understanding of the fact that **the individual correlations may vanish and still the overall correlation may be non-zero**. But I am not looking for this verification from the formula. Is there a visual explanation that one can come up with?

By the way, is there a particular name for $r$ as defined above? Any reference where this shows up in descriptive statistics will be great.

Comment: The $r$ defined above is just the ordinary Pearson correlation computed from $x$ and $y$ across all the groups. So it isn't a generalisation and it doesn't have a special name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one option:

There is zero correlation for groups within vertical lines.
But overall correlation is positive.

[image: correlation scatter]

Comment: Yea, you are right. Editing to a better example.